# Don't show white spaces in regex output

Tags: php, regex

I need to match everything but not the white spaces

For example in this string : `16790 - 140416 / 3300`

I want to have the following result made by regex (and PHP) without white spaces: `140416/3300`

I used : `\s+\d+\s+-\s+(\d+\s+\/\s+\d+)` and of course it gave me the results with the whitespaces:

`140416 / 3300`

How could I have a match 1 result without white spaces ?

Thank you

Comment: `preg_match()` can only return what was in the original string. If you want to modify it, you need to do that after receiving the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = "16790 - 140416 / 3300";
$result = preg_replace('%.*?(\d+)\s+/\s+(\d+)%', '$1/$2', $subject);
echo $result;
// 140416/3300
```

http://regex101.com/r/oV4hN0

Comment: @HamZa I'm not following you

Comment: I need also to match the / just no white spaces . No way with just regex please?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just removing an unknown number of spaces and tabs from a string, you can use

```
$result = preg_replace('~\s*~', '', $subject);
```

If you're matching the whole pattern you gave (not just the division), you can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)~', '\1-\2/\3', $subject);
```

Finally, and this might be the best, if you'd like to remove spaces around operators such as =,*,-,/ when they are surrounded by digits, you can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(\d)\s*([+*/-])\s*(\d)~', '\1\2\3', $subject);
```